# more efficient use of itertools.groupby()

Tags: python, python-itertools

I am trying to enhance my knowledge of the `itertools` library, since it's so generally useful. To that end, I'm trying to solve an interview puzzler I came across. A large portion of it involves sequentially counting the number of grouped and repeated digits within a number. For example, for the number:

```
1223444556
```

I want:

```
[(1,1),(2,2),(1,3),(3,4),(2,5),(1,6)]
```

which is to say, from left to right, there is 1 one, 2 twos, 1 three, and so forth.

Here is my current code:

```
from itertools import groupby
groups_first = [int(''.join(v)[0]) for k,v in groupby(str(1223444556))]
counts = [len(''.join(v)) for k,v in groupby(str(1223444556))]
zip(counts,groups_first)
```

It works, but what I would like to know is whether there is a more compact way of doing this that bypasses zipping two lists together. Any thoughts? I think this may go to doing some sort of lambda function in groupby(), but I can't see it yet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
[(sum(1 for _ in v), int(k)) for k,v in groupby(str(1223444556))]
```

Comment: Accepted because of your timing comments below. I naively would have gone with @DSM's solution though. Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably just write

```
>>> n = 1223444556
>>> [(len(list(g)), int(k)) for k,g in groupby(str(n))]
[(1, 1), (2, 2), (1, 3), (3, 4), (2, 5), (1, 6)]
```

Comment: Uggghhh. Why do I always make it so hard on myself? This is what I was shooting for. Will accept ASAP.

Comment: No need to rush, maybe someone will come up with something more clever.  I like @DavidRobinson's solution too, and it doesn't need to construct the list.  [Unless they were very large I wouldn't worry about it, admittedly.]

Comment: True, I didn't see that -- I got scared off by the _ :P

Comment: Both are good solutions, but incidentally, `timeit.timeit("[(sum(1 for _ in v), int(k)) for k,v in groupby(s)]", setup="s = '1223444556'; from itertools import groupby", number=100000)` vs `timeit.timeit("[(len(list(v)), int(k)) for k,v in groupby(s)]", setup="s = '1223444556'; from itertools import groupby", number=100000)` indicates my method is about 30% faster.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably opt for collections instead:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c = Counter('1223444556')
>>> c.items()
[('1', 1), ('3', 1), ('2', 2), ('5', 2), ('4', 3), ('6', 1)]
```

if the order is important (as you say in your comment), this may no longer be the most efficient method. But for full consideration, you could do this:

```
>>> t = c.items()
>>> t = sorted(t)
```

And if you want y, x to be listed as x, y, you could then do this:

```
>>> t = [(y, x) for x, y in t]
>>> print t
[(1, '1'), (2, '2'), (1, '3'), (3, '4'), (2, '5'), (1, '6')]
```

One value of this method is that the repeated element is listed as a string, so there is no confusion about which number comes from the original list and which number indicates frequency.

Comment: That is efficient, but I also need the order preserved as well.